# unsuccessfully trying to get second spinner to get set depending on first spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to create an app to calculate different capacity totals based on drive type, RAID type and number of drives.

I've been looking at the different examples on here and other sites trying to get this to work to no avail. No matter what I try to do I get a "java.lang.NullPointerException" when running the app. Below is the code that I have so far(am just trying to test whether the spinners will dynamically set depending on the choice of the first spinner before going on):

activity_capacity_calculation.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".CapacityCalculation" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerDrive"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/drive_selection" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerCapacity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/capacity_selection" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerRAID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/RAID_selection" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerNumber"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/number_of_drives" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/capacity_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/capacity_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

CapcityCalcultaion.java

```
package com.jrod.storagecalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class CapacityCalculation extends Activity {

    private Spinner spinnerDrive, spinnerCapacity;

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stringArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(CapacityCalculation.this, R.array.drive_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> nlsasAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(CapacityCalculation.this, R.array.nlsas_capacity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> sasAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(CapacityCalculation.this, R.array.sas_capacity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ssdAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(CapacityCalculation.this, R.array.ssd_capacity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capacity_calculation);
        setupActionBar();


            spinnerDrive = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDrive);
            spinnerDrive.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
            spinnerDrive.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String check = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    if (check.startsWith("NL-SAS")) {
                    spinnerCapacity.setAdapter(nlsasAdapter);
                    }else if (check.startsWith("SAS")) {
                    spinnerCapacity.setAdapter(sasAdapter);
                    }else if (check.startsWith("SSD")) {
                    spinnerCapacity.setAdapter(ssdAdapter);
                    }
                }


                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){

                }
            });

    private void setupActionBar() {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

and my logcat output:

```
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319): Process: com.jrod.storagecalculator, PID: 29319
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.jrod.storagecalculator/com.jrod.storagecalculator.CapacityCalculation}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2131)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:783)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:430)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at com.jrod.storagecalculator.CapacityCalculation.<init>(CapacityCalculation.java:15)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
03-10 15:07:23.155: E/AndroidRuntime(29319):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Your problem is on line 15: `...(CapacityCalculation.java:15)`, giving the stack trace it's probably one of the  `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource` ones. What's on that line?

Comment: ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stringArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.drive_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Comment: Try initializing these Adapters on the `onCreate` method

Comment: when I initialize them in the onCreate method, only original StringArrayAdapter is ok, the rest of the adapters bring up warnings that they are not used (not the case before)

Comment: figured it out, needed to declare the rest of the adapters as final. Thanks for letting me in on how to read the logcat properly!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line:

```
spinnerCapacity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCapacity);
```

Comment: I added the line, but I still get the NullPointerExeception